# How to test if an enum variable was not assigned

Tags: objective-c, enums

If I have a NSString variable I can test if the variable was not assigned yet by doing

```
if (!variable) {
  [self doSomething];
}
```

but what about this?

```
typedef enum {

    car = 100,
    home,
    flower,

} object; 

object myVar;

if (!myVar)  // ???  is this correct?
```

is this really testing if the variable has been already assigned or contains a value?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An `enum` is basically an `int` variable. You would need to initialize the enum variable with some value that isn't valid for the enum definition.

One option might be:

```
object myVar = kUnknownType;

if (myVar == kUnknownType) {
    // not yet assigned
}
```

Comment: I was trying to do another thing, but never mind, you have the correct answer. Thanks.